# Extract all the gallery images from specific URL with PHP

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents

I am trying to extract all the images from a specific URL and store it in a specific folder. I tried doing some research but all i could get is some list of images only.

```
<?php
// $url_image = $_GET['url'];
$url_image = 'https://www.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wedding-inspiration/elegant-yet-modern/';
$homepage = file_get_contents($url_image);
preg_match_all("{<img\\s*(.*?)src=('.*?'|\".*?\"|[^\\s]+)(.*?)\\s*/?>}ims", $homepage, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
// print_r($matches);
foreach ($matches as $val) {

    $pos = strpos($val[2],"/"); 
    $link = substr($val[2],1,-1);
    if($pos == 1)
        echo "https://www.thebridesofoklahoma.com" . $link;
    else
        echo $link;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me to get all the list of Image url used in gallery only. Please refer to this webpage: https://www.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wedding-inspiration/elegant-yet-modern/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Regex to parse HTML. Use DomDocument.
The available images are wrapped into a div, so it easy to find them with XPath.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://www.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wedding-inspiration/elegant-yet-modern/');
$img = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach($img->query('//div/img') as $image) {
    echo $image->getAttribute('src'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

```
https://images.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/21161012/Logo-final-01-1024x339.jpg
https://images.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wp-content/uploads/profiles/1564/08234701/bl_bartending_horiz_reversed.jpg
https://images.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/26203513/Screen-Shot-2021-01-26-at-8.32.49-PM-850x1024.png
https://images.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wp-content/uploads/profiles/65/10015531/static.squarespace.com_.jpg
https://images.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/17131459/IMG_2157-1024x965.jpg
https://images.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/04143016/kgc-photography-logo-copy-1024x479.png
https://images.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/25104302/FB4A0746-420x290.jpg
https://images.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/24120412/harvard-99-420x290.jpg
https://images.thebridesofoklahoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/22133337/Aaron_Snow_Photography_Hall_Wedding.AES_0256-420x290.jpg
```

Comment: Your code is pulling images from the side bar. I tried targeting the gallery div with $img->query('//div[@class="Test"]/img' but it is not returning anything.

Comment: That's all images that are available from URLs HTML. You can't load those who are injected later via javascript React component - except you are using a V8 engine. `<div data-reactroot="" class="asg" id="awesome-gallery-323705-1">`

Comment: Can you give me some hints on how to extract all those gallery images. Thank You in advance

Comment: You can't without evaluating Javascript, because this gallery component is generated with Javascript, after the page (HTML) is loaded. Curl or file_get_contents() is not able to evaluate Javascript generated by the React framework. It gives you the HTML fetched from that URL. Open site in Browser and press CTRL+U to see the fetched(!) HTML. Then compare with the parsed in Inspector. Notice the difference?